# Python While loop selecting the cheapest price at available volume

Tags: python

I got a list of data of 8 columns: Volume1,Volume2,Volume3,Volume4 and their corresponding price Price1,Price2,Price3,Price4 
Row unit: time (data at four different time)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Volume1' : [100, 500, 300, 500], 
                   'Price1' : [10.02, 10.32, 10.32, 10.21],
                   'Volume2' : [200, 500, 300, 500], 
                   'Price2' : [11.02, 12.02, 11.32, 12.21],
                  'Volume3' : [100, 400, 300, 500], 
                   'Price3' : [13.22, 13.30, 12.32, 13.21],
                  'Volume4' : [300, 500, 300, 200], 
                   'Price4' : [14.02, 14.32, 13.32, 14.21]})
```

Now I got a list of Volume that I want to buy
[350,600,400,1000]

for example: for volume = 350, I firstly want to buy it at price 1 at time1 (10.02), but I can only get 100 volume, so then I have to buy the rest at price2 and price 3
same for volume 600 - I can only get 500 at price of 10.32, then I have to get the rest at the price of 12.02

I am trying to calculate the total cost. However, it takes long to make a `if & elif & elif` loop. How can I use a `while` loop to achieve this instead?

My current code:
Volume = [350,600,400,1000]

```
Matrix = df.as_matrix()
Cost = np.zeros((len(Volume),1))
for i in range(0,len(Volume)-1):
    n = 1
    while ( Volume[i] - df.item(i,n) > 0):
        Cost[i] = Cost[i] + df.item(i,n) * df.item((i,n-1))
        Volume[i] = Volume[i] -  df.item((i,n))
        n = n+1
        if n > 4:
          break
```

but this code does not return me the desired value, can someone please help me to figure out my mistake?

Comment: Could we perhaps summarise by saying you want to buy a holding as soon as possible, selecting from available volumes at any time by buying at the cheapest price first?

Comment: Yes thank you for the summarization